# ObjectInputStream available() method doesn't work as expected (Java)

Tags: java

I've been trying to figure out why a method I've written to read objects from a file didn't work and realized that the available() method of ObjectInputStream gave 0 even though the file wasn't fully read.
The method did work after I've used the FileInputStream available() method instead to determine the EOF and it worked!

Why doesn't the method work for ObjectInputStram while it works for FileInputStream?

Here's the code:

```
public static void getArrFromFile() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Product p;
    FileInputStream in= new FileInputStream(fName);
    ObjectInputStream input= new ObjectInputStream(in);
    while(in.available()>0){
        p=(Product)input.readObject();
        if (p.getPrice()>3000)
            System.out.println(p);
    }
    input.close();
```

P.S-
I've read that I should use the EOF exception instead of available() for this, but I just wanna know why this doesn't work.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 4):

Because, as the javadoc tells, `available()` returns an estimation of the number of bytes that can be read **without blocking**. The base InputStream implementation always returns 0, because this is a valid estimation. But whatever it returns, the fact that it returns 0 doesn't mean that there is nothing to read anymore. Only that the stream can't guarantee that at least one byte can be read without blocking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still, I don't see the difference. Why doesn't the method work for ObjectInputStram while it works for FileInputStream?

Comment: Because, for some reason, ObjectInputStream can't guarantee (or chose not to offer such a guarantee) that some bytes could be read without blocking, whereas FileInputStream can. You would have to dive into the code of those two classes to precisely understand what their available() class does. But this is pretty useless, since available() is almost never useful, and certainly not in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not documented clearly I have realized from experience that it has to do with dynamic data. If your class only contains statically typed data, then `available()` is able to estimate the size. If there are dynamic data in your object, like lists etc, then it is not possible to make that estimation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide comments under questions rather than as a direct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `available()` method just tells how many bytes can be read without blocking. It's not very useful in regular code, but people see the name and erroneously think it does something else.

So in short: don't use `available()`, it's not the right method to use. Streams indicate ending differently, such as returning -1 or in `ObjectInputStream`'s case, throwing an `EOFException`.

Answer (score 0):

I found some trick! If you still want to use `.available()` to read all objects to the end, you can add an integer (ex: `out.writeInt(0)`) before adding each Object (ex: `out.writeObject(obj)`) when you write to the file and also read integer before reading each Object. So `.available()` can read byte left on file and won't be crash! Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Use available function of InputStream instead of ObjectInputStream. Then if there is any data, get them as an object.
Something like:

```
if(inputStreamObject.available() > 0){
 Object anyName =  objectInputStreamObject.readObject();
}
```

You can get the inputStreamObject directly from the Socket.
I used it and the problem solved.